# How to get daily data report using python3

Tags: python-3.x

I will try to explain my question as clear as i can.It would be so nice if you help me out.

(1)I am working in a tech support company where I am working on storage box like VNX and XtremeIo. I want to fetch the report of the data usage on each of the storage pool available in the storage box.

(2) Since the data keep on varying daily , so I want the daily report to be generated at a particular time everyday, and the report I should get it in my mail(outlook, gmail etc..) using python language.

Thank You!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!!  This site is not a coding service, so you need to provide some code to obtain assistance with your problem.

Comment: Please familiarize with this FAQ and repost your question -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve